# StructureMap : EqualToAppSetting with non string constructor argument

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap

Given

```
public class Blah : IBlah 
{
    public Blah(decimal argument)
    {
    }
}
```

When

```
ForRequestedType<IBlah>()
    .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Blah>()
    .WithCtorArg("argument")
    .EqualToAppSetting("argument_app_setting_key")
```

Then StructureMap throws the following exception

```
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Decimal
```

Is there any way to use the EqualToAppSetting with non-string arguments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the EqualToAppSetting method.  Could you not just reference System.Configuration and cast the app setting yourself?  Like this...

```
      ForRequestedType<IBlah>()
        .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Blah>()
        .WithCtorArg("blah")
        .EqualTo(Convert.ToDecimal(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["argument_app_setting_key"]));
```